# Python Seaborn plotting time series with tsplot get syskill due to consume lot of memory ram

Tags: python, numpy, seaborn, timeserieschart

I am using [Seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/)

I want to make a time series [plots](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.tsplot.html)

It has 310.498 dots like

```
df = pd.DataFrame(loQueQuieroGraficar,columns['bucket','value','label'])
```

When I ran

```
sns.tsplot(melted_df, time='bucket', unit='Dummy', condition='etiqueta', value='valor')
```

consumes a lot of memory ram (In mac like 50 GB, in Windows less) but it finished by a syskill due to a memory error.

Do you know how to resolve it?